# Custom Error Response Settings and a redirect to index.html with SEO?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I am using the Custom Error Response Settings for my AngularJS SPA so that when a user tries to go directly to a page and it gives a 404 not found then it redirects to index.html.

What I would like to know is does this in any way cause a problem for the search engines or would they not even notice the 404 and the redirect to the index.html?

Comment: I guess you don't want to disable HTML5-Mode and just navigate via hashbang?

Comment: I could consider that if there's no other solution but would really like to find a clean solution if possible.  Just not sure what this would be as I have not found much about this documented on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) return 200 on those urls.

Based on your tag, I presume you're hosting on CloudFront. You can there set a custom response code 200 for 404 errors, by editing a CloudFront distribution and going to **Error Pages** tab.

[image]